# Creating flashcards from pdfs with mathematical symbols

Tags: pdf, anki

I am studying mathematics and I need to create flashcards from some pdfs, for example [this pdf](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/download/fields.pdf#nameddest=09FA).

What I did so far was to take a screenshot of some paragraphs, create a question and paste the image as an answer, but I noticed that it takes much time and many times I get tired. Is there a more efficient way of creating flashcards from such pdfs (actually I also mean faster)? Or maybe whether there are some keyboard shortcuts that I am not aware of. Of course everybody needs to take time and think about when creating a flashcard, but I know exactly what types of question I need to create.

Comment: From the pdf, I'm afraid there won't be a better way than taking screenshots. However, if you have access to the LaTeX file that was used to create this pdf, then you could use [genanki](https://github.com/kerrickstaley/genanki) to automatically parse the latex file, and for instance detect definitions and create one new Anki note for each definition, etc. Anki supports MathJax and Latex, so math formulas should not be a problem.